# How to send a command using AppleScript to terminal one by one and save the output, which is not writable to file anywhere?

Tags: terminal, applescript

So, I have a problem. I have downloaded a program from the web. And it's a command line app. I have written a code, which generated some `n-k` commands to the app. I have written them into an output file. I can write an app in Python, but it freezes on some of the commands. I have tested them manually and seems like there are two issues:

1. Commands must be run one-by-one;
2. Some of the commands give an output like `bla-bla-bla`, this thing is not written into an output file. So, if I run a command `./app -p /file1 -o /file2 -s -a smth- > /fileOutput.txt` The `fileOutput.txt` is empty, though in the terminal, there's is this `bla-bla-bla` message, stating, that something is wrong. If the command gives `bla-bla-bla` the app may freeze for a while.

Here is what I want to do:

1. `CD` into folder, the containing app;
2. `For command in fileWithCommands` perform command and start the next, only when the previous finishes;
3. If the command gives message, containing `bla-bla-bla` (cause it may look like `file1 bla-bla-bla`), write the command and this strange output into file badOutputs.txt.

Have never done applescript before. However, this's what I've done so far:

```
set theFile to "/Users/MeUser/Desktop/firstCommand"
set fileHandle to open for access theFile
set arrayCommand to paragraphs of (read fileHandle)
#I have found the previous code here: http://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/applescript-read-file-into-list-array-examples
close access fileHandle
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd /Users/MeUser/Desktop/anApp/"
    repeat with command in arrayCommand
        do script command
    end repeat
end tell
```

Though there's a problem, if in one window the commands make up a huge queue. Without `window 1` cd and the command are in different windows. And I am still unable to save the output.

UPDATE

Did with accordance to **@Mark Setchell**'s recommendations. So now I have such code:

```
set theFile to "/Users/meUser/Desktop/firstCommand"
set fileHandle to open for access theFile
set arrayCommand to paragraphs of (read fileHandle)
close access fileHandle
repeat with command in arrayCommand
    do shell script "cd /Users/meUser/Desktop/App/; " & command
end repeat
```

To the command I have added the following:

```
2>&1 /Users/meUser/Desktop/errorOut.txt
```

However, the apple script says that a mistake of the app is the mistake of the script. I.e.: file corrupted, app fails. I want it to write into error file where has it failed and move to the next command, while the script just fails.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you, it works, though it's a bit unclear, how can I write both command and error to the same file? I need to get it, to see, for instance, which file was corrupted or unsuitable. Also, how can I append those outputs into one file? I have just tested manually and it re-writes the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not a complete solution, but more than a comment and easier to format this way...

**First Issue**

Your command-line app which writes on the Terminal may be writing to `stderr` rather than `stdout`. Try redirecting `stderr` to the same place as `stdout` by using

```
./app -p ... > /FileOutput.txt 2>&1
```

**Second Issue**

You cannot do:

```
do shell script cd somewhere
do shell script do_something
```

because each `do shell script` will execute in **a separate, unrelated process**. So your first process will start - **in the default directory like all processes** - and correctly change directory and then exit. Then your second process will start - **in the default directory like all processes** - and try to run your command. Rather than that, you can do this:

```
do shell script "cd somewhere; do_something"
```

which starts a single process which changes directory and then runs your command line program there.

**Issue Three**

Why do you want to send your commands to Terminal anyway? Does the user need to see something in Terminal - seems unlikely because you want to capture the output, don't you? Can't you just run your commands using `do shell script`?

**Issue Four**

If you want to keep your normal output separate from your error output, you can do:

```
./app ... params ... > OutputFile.txt 2> errors.txt
```

**Suggestion 1**

You can retain all the errors from all the scripts and accumulate them in a single file like this:

```
./app .. params .. >> results.txt 2>&1
```

That may enable you to deal with errors separately later.

**Suggestion 2**

You can capture the output of your shell script into an Applescript variable, say `ScriptOutput`, like this, then you can parse it:

```
set ScriptOutput to do shell script "..."
```

**Suggestion 3**

If errors caused by your script are stopping your loop, you can enclose them in a `try block` like this so they are handled and everything continues:

```
try
   do shell script "..."
on error errMsg
   display dialog "ERROR: " & errMsg
end try
```

Comment: How do I insert my command inside, as I am iterating through the array with commands? About the shell. I am a bit confused with it; also I am confused with how to call the commands one-by-one. I was trying to do somewhat like `bash myCommands` and it made a frozen mess of all the commands, because it wasn't executing them one-by-one somehow O_O Maybe I just don't get smth, but at least it's what I see.

Comment: I can't see your commands :-). Basically you would create a string starting with `"cd somewhere; "` and then append each of your commands to that string one at a time and run it.

Comment: `repeat with command in arrayCommand`, I did: `do script "cd"`; `do script command`. How do I make it in your fashion `do shell script "cd somewhere; do_something"` is it somewhat like `do shell script "cd somewhere; %s" command`?

Comment: thanks a lot, I have almost finished it. Can you, please, have a look at the update?

Comment: Not sure what to say - what you have looks ok but I can't see the commands you are actually executing.

Comment: OK. So the app is called isoMIF it's used in science. Can be downloaded [here](http://bcb.med.usherbrooke.ca/isomif_locally.php) I am trying to perform this command  ` ./getCleft -p ./hive/pdb/1E8X.pdb -o ./hive/clefts/1E8X -s -a ATP3000A-` But cause I have several nk files, I don't want to do that manually. The actual command on which it fails is: ./getcleft_mac_x86_64 -p `/Users/User/Downloads/PDB.EXISTING/16pk.pdb -o /Users/User/Documents/CLEFTS/16pk -s -a EPE430A- 2>&1 /Users/User/Desktop/errorOut.txt`, when script reaches it: `error "Residue EPE430A is not apart a cleft." number 1`

Comment: In order to run this command you also need this file: [link](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/16PK.pdb) Save it and change the part in the command `/Users/User/Downloads/PDB.EXISTING/16pk.pdb` to where you store the file. I have noticed that there may be mistakes with the several files. I just want the script to write to me, where are the mistakes, what the app doesn't like and then cope in a different way with the stubborn entries.

Comment: So copy that exact command and start a Terminal and paste it in and see what happens in Terminal. Once you get it working in Terminal you can then get it working in your Applescript.

Comment: In the terminal it gives me such a thing: `Residue EPE430A is not apart a cleft.` I want to pass all of those commands, but exactly one by one. If there's an error, simply put it into file for the error outputs and move to the next command. The script instead of that fails on the error. I know that there are errors, I actually want to find them in such a way.